# How to wait for a command in a scripted telnet session?

Tags: sleep, wait, telnet, netcat

Automatically sending over files through telnet works fine. But how do I make telnet "wait" for a process which I started in this way, in this case `nc` that receives a file? The robot here is at `192.168.0.45` and my laptop is at `192.168.0.10`.

```
{
sleep 1
echo "root"
echo "cd /flash"
echo "nc 192.168.0.10 10001 >lasertest"
sleep 5
} | telnet 192.168.0.45 23
```

There are a few questions like this [1], but non of them seem to want to have this synchronous behaviour. In the above the process waits for 5 seconds, just assuming that this is enough for the transmission. If it is not long enough, the file transmitted in this way will just be truncated and is corrupted.

[1] [Telnet inside a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264044/telnet-inside-a-shell-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `expect` script should do.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn telnet 192.168.0.45 23
expect login
send "root\n"
send "cd /flash\n"
send "nc 192.168.0.10 10001 >lasertest\n"
send "exit\n"
expect eof
```

If the login prompt doesn't contain "login", change the "expect" command suitably.

Comment: So, `expect` is necessary here? How does `send` know that a command has finished?

Comment: `expect` is one tool that does what you need - not necessarily the only one. - `send` doesn't know that a command has finished, and it doesn't need to know. It suffices that the whole procedure runs to its end, and the `expect eof` takes care of that.

Comment: If you absolutely want to wait for single commands to have finished, you can intersperse `expect` with [part of] the prompt string.

Comment: Yes, that would work, would you mind edit your answer so I can accept it. Stated as this it won't wait for `nc` to be finished.

Comment: Sorry, I know understand, the `expect eof` should enforce this already. I will check it later and except it without changes.

Comment: Indeed, with `expect eof` this works splendidly. `nc` will transfer everything and `expect` will neatly wait for an EOF signal which will only happen after `nc` finishes. Minor adaptation: `logout` does not exist on all machines, replace by `exit`.

Comment: Good point... replaced. Minor clarification: EOF happens only after `logout` or `exit`.